# Can Blender still be used commercially since Java licensing has changed?

Tags: licensing

As I was installing Blender, I was prompted to update my version of Java, but I don't want to update it because of the [Java licensing change](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk-faqs.html).
Can Blender be used with an older version of Java that predates the licensing change?

Comment: As far as I know, Blender is not built upon Java at all. Why this question?

Comment: I think this was just a coincidence

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because licensing and legal questions are out of the scope of this site.

Answer (score 6):

Blender is made with Python and C/C++, not Java. Also Blender is free and open source software that can be used commercially in any condition.

In completement a link to [Blender's licence page](https://www.blender.org/about/license/).

> Blender is released under the GNU General Public License (GPL, or
> “free software”).
>
> This license grants people a number of freedoms:
>
> ```
> You are free to use Blender, for any purpose
> You are free to distribute Blender
> You can study how Blender works and change it
> You can distribute changed versions of Blender
> ```
>
> The GPL strictly aims at protecting these freedoms, requiring everyone
> to share their modifications when they also share the software in
> public. That aspect is commonly referred to as Copyleft.
>
> The Blender Foundation and its projects on blender.org are committed
> to preserving Blender as free software.